# what is a console app mainly used for?

Tags: winforms, console-application

I have always used winforms to do my projects but I have never really explored the console application. I have seen some videos of different programs done in console applications for example, games, engines, display images using the keyboard keys and more but what exactly is a console app for?

Comment: The COmmand Line Interface of Video Games where you can type Cheats. Well.. Console Applications do not require designing of a UI. Most useful for developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is in danger of being closed ... but I'll try to answer.

Really console applications have a history - in the days when a console, which may have been a teletype with a single output line, to a tty style console with a several line screen was the main UI for computers from mainframes to personal computers running CP/M, DOS or one of almost hundreds of different operating systems.

Whilst @james_schorr is parially correct, some technical people still find console apps to be efficient ways of performing certain sorts of operations - even with user interaction.  For example I use git and mercurial from the command line in preference to a UI like tortoise.

They have some advantages (especially on Unix and Linux) because you can combine the commands in scripts using pipes (i.e. where standard out of one is fed directly into standard input of the next) to form very powerful operations.

Answer (score 3):

More backend types of things, typically for apps that require no user interaction (backup jobs, etc… that run on a scheduled basis).

Answer (score 0):

I use them primarily for command line apps that perform repetitive tasks. You can support input parameters through the args array parameter to the Main method.

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity. Throwawy apps. Test apps. Logging consoles. Ensuring it will work on Mono and/or from a command line. Or just laziness. Take your pick.

Specifically text-based programs, which represent decades of our programming heritage.

Before Windowing came about mainstream, users were quite happy to work in in console based text programs.

I can remember when we could write real business/financial apps in DOS or green-terminal UNIX that people actually wanted.

Comment: Based on everyone's responses it is an app that does simple functions like debugging and displays simple information. So It could be used as a support app that does functions behind the scenes of other apps. I was thinking of doing a simple project using the console but I'm not sure what to do though, but Thanks for the information everyone.

Answer (score 0):

They could be used for virtually any task, but are mainly used for automated tasks, tasks that don't require too much advanced user intervention, tasks where a GUI would consume too much CPU power, tasks where large amounts of data are used as inputs or outputs that the user doesn't need to view, etc.